# how to use OsmDroid for navigation in android

Tags: android, navigation, osmdroid, geopoints

totally new to osmdroid and navigation world.

I just want to know, if a user enters the location name or post code ( the location where he wants to go to ) how I'm suppose to search it in the map ?

and another thing, if I already got the GeoPoint of the destination how I'm going to do the actual searching algorithm from my location to the destination ?

It would be really helpful if a sample code is provided.

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest having a look at `OSMBonusPack`.

This library does exactly what you want. You can either choose to use it or to look at the sources to understand how to do such things. It is here: https://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/

Comment: can't I do it without the OSMBonusPack. I'm trying to do it with the minimal number of libraries.

Comment: You can, certainly. Just have a look to see how to do it.

Comment: I'm not sure how to look into the source code, can you just send it to me or attach it in here. Or tell me how to to do it. 

Sorry for annoying but I'm totally new with no experience.

Comment: @user3880883 No problem. Sources, executables and javadocs can be found here: https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/wiki/Downloads